# Similar background for Blockquote and Preformatted(code)

Tags: support, feature-request, text-formatting

On AskUbuntu there is similar background-formatting for **Blockquote** text and **Preformatted code** text.

Example-1 (with preformatted/coded text):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Example-2 (with block-quoted text):

> sudo apt-get update

The similarity makes it easy to confuse them.

---

In this example

> Try first `sudo apt-get -f install` so that...

The code `sudo apt-get -f install` is not easily picked out because of the whole-statement's block-quote format.

It should be easier to differentiate these types of formatted text.

---

On other S.E sites there is a different colouring to the background which makes it easier to see the difference. Here's an example

[image: screen]

I'm not asking for it to be exactly like this, but some differentiation is definitely needed here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: strange, wasn't the code a darker color before?

Comment: @Mateo It does have a slightly darker color on main ([Example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount)), but not on meta (Though I'm not sure if this was the case before). Either way, I prefer how a blockquote looks very different from a code block on other sites.

Comment: oh, that explains it, I think the difference used to be greater as well

Comment: I wonder what have happened to this, is there no official statement somewhere? I think this would be really useful to have them really distinct from code lines.

Answer (score 12):

I think We should adopt the color background quote style with the vertical rule as:

1. It is clearly different
2. It would help with the confusion of formatting code as a quote.
3. We could use a light aubergine consistent with Ubuntu colors:

---

[image]

[image]
These might be too dark.

---

[image]

Comment: Not sure about it being aubergine though...

Comment: @Tim - perhaps the colour could be set in user preferences :D

Comment: Yes, possibly :) I think the yellow is better - or see my suggestion at the bottom - no colour change.

Comment: Maybe a Light orange? Oh, The grey with the rule looks good as well.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the grey, I think they colours breaks the colour scheme...

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that we keep the same colour for the quote, but instead just add the rule along the side.

[image]

<sup>I took the line colouring from the yellow one on Meta.SE- it goes from (33,255,241) to (35,255,199), a change of (2,0,-42) so I did the same with the grey, from (0,0,238) to (2,0,196). These are all HSL colour numbers.</sup>

I also think that the code should change colour, maybe to be slightly darker than the quote, so that you can see a difference when there is quoted code:

> This is a quote. `This is embedded code`. Not much difference.

The embedded code background is #dcdcdc. This could possibly only happen when it is embedded in quotes? But a permanent change wouldn't be bad.

[image]

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Yes, this is a nice middle ground. I sometimes find the background coloring of the beta sites to be very glaring.

Answer (score 2):

I think having a different color for blockquotes and code makes sense, because they serve two different purposes. As you've shown sometimes you may have code inside a blockquote, and it would be nice to be able to visibly distinguish it. I would suggest staying away from highlighter colors since to me they say this is the important part not this is the quote, but I might be a bit biased on that since I would actually like to see a highlighter feature implemented. The code wrapper is actually kind of like highlighting except it as well stays away from highlighter colors to distinguish that it's for code.

There is a forum software called Simple Machine Forums which I think has a nice quoting setup; perhaps we could take a page from their book. You can find some examples on this page: http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=523494.0 . Here is a screenshot of one:

[image: Simple Machine Forums Quote Example]

As you can see above, on S.M.F. their postings have a gray background so their quotes have a darker grayish-purple color. This makes them stand back, but different from highlighting which makes things pop out. I'm not saying we should use the same purpeish-gray color on here, because our background is much lighter than S.M.F.'s. AskUbuntu has a white background so perhaps a medium gray would be an equivalent to the S.M.F. strategy? I also think having quotation marks would be an asset to help make it clearer that it is a quote.

Currently both blockquotes and code wrappers use #EEEEEE, but I think blockquotes should perhaps be switched to #CCCCCC so they fall back. As seen in my examples below. Please ignore the misuse of the code wrappers, I couldn't think of anything to type.

**Example #1:**

[image: Example One Of Blockquote And Code Wrappers]

**Example #2:**

[image: Example Two Of Blockquote And Code Wrappers]

Comment: The problem here is that blockquotes are not always used for quotes - like code blocks are not always used for code, bullets points etc. Would be nice a form of formatting though.

Comment: Plus the big quote is pretty tacky.