# Could our quote style be different to the code style?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Related](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10347/similar-background-for-blockquote-and-preformattedcode). This suggestion has been added as an [answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11637/186134).

On Ask Ubuntu, this is what our code looks like compared to our quote style:

```
Code here is obviously code.
```

> But quotes look almost the same.

Okay, so there is some difference - font and width of block.

But on (This is meta SE) they are obviously different:

[image]

Could we have it that our quote block is less similar to the code block? My suggestion wouldn't be a new colour, but that you have a dark grey line at the edge:

[image]

The dark grey is (2,0,196) in HSL, or c4c4c4ff in RGB

<sup>I took the line colouring from the yelow one - it goes from (33,255,241) to (35,255,199), a change of (2,0,-42) so I did the same with the grey, from (0,0,238) to (2,0,196). These are all HSL colour numbers.</sup>

```
banana
```

> banana `hello`

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10347/similar-background-for-blockquote-and-preformattedcode

Comment: @Dan possibly a dupe atually?

Comment: I would ask for a different opinion, but maybe add your solution as an answer to that question instead of duping it.

Comment: I personally like the current styling..

Comment: @Seth but it is hard to tell the difference...?

Comment: I don't think it is hard to tell the difference, personally.

Comment: Okay then :) If you see the related link, then another reason is that quote embedded code is the same colour (or almost identical on the main site)

Comment: I agree with you tim, write up the answer and get a vote.

Comment: @don, it is on the other question.